# Is it possible to specify exact number of fractional digits in DecimalFormat parsing?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I'm using `DecimalFormat` to parse strings representing decimal numbers. What I'd like to have is to a parsing function which checks the exact number of fractional digits in strings. In details, I want to check that the string has exactly two fractional digits (e.g., `"1.10"` is valid, `"1.1"` is not valid).

Is it possible to have such behavior with `DecimalFormat`? The instance built with following method doesn't work.

```
private static DecimalFormat decimalFormat() {
    final DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00", decimalFormatSymbols);
    decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
    return decimalFormat;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "checks"? `DecimalFormat` is not meant for input validation.

Comment: @shmosel I'd like to have a `ParseException` if string has less or more fractional digits. Is it possible? Otherwise I should match the string with a regular expression.

Comment: Just use a regex. DecimalFormat is used to display a value, not to check the form of a string.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation on `setMinimumIntegerDigits` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMinimumIntegerDigits-int-

> newValue - the minimum number of integer digits to be shown; [...].

As far as I can understand, this does not act as a requirement, only as a format for the output.

Looking through the available functions for `DecimalFormat`, I can't see anything that would give you the number of fraction digits.

BUT, since you are using `setParseBigDecimal(true)`, parsing a string would then give you a `BigDecimal` which gives you access to the `precision` function : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#precision--

So what I suggest if you absolutely want to check the result of the parse (and not the string itself) for the correct number of digits is :

- set the minimum fraction digits to 0
- take the string
- parse it in `BigDecimal`
- use the `BigDecima::precision` function to check if the number of digits is correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: True, it would return only the number of digits right of the dicimal point.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to validate a condition rather than convert a string to a given format. You can use regular expressions to do this. Here's an example method that I believe does what you want

```
public boolean hasTwoFractionalDigits(String text) {
    return Pattern.compile("^\\d+\\.\\d\\d$").matcher(text).find();
}
```

This will return true for "10.33" but false for "10.3". If this doesn't answer your question let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regular expression works but I prefer the solution propose by Oliver Samson in the response above.

Answer (score 0):

if price has decimal(.) then decimal(.) always have digit as prefix and suffix both. i.e '*0.0*'
integer price is acceptable.
max 2 fractional digit.

5, 5.0, 5.00 Accept
0, 0.0, 0.00  5. .5, 5.000, ., .0, .00, .000, 0. String = Error